# prometheus samples are too old or are too far into the future

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

prometheus and node exporter both use chrony to sync time.

```
[root@MiWiFi-R3-srv node_exporter-0.18.1.linux-amd64]# timedatectl 
      Local time: Sun 2019-07-07 13:48:15 CST
  Universal time: Sun 2019-07-07 05:48:15 UTC
        RTC time: Sun 2019-07-07 05:48:15
       Time zone: Asia/Shanghai (CST, +0800)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

```
[root@MiWiFi-R3-srv prometheus]# timedatectl 
      Local time: Sun 2019-07-07 13:48:44 CST
  Universal time: Sun 2019-07-07 05:48:44 UTC
        RTC time: Sun 2019-07-07 05:48:45
       Time zone: Asia/Shanghai (CST, +0800)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

but prometheus complain about time is wrong

```
level=warn ts=2019-07-07T05:46:02.960Z caller=scrape.go:1199 component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=prometheus target=http://192.168.2.22:9100/metrics msg="Error on ingesting samples that are too old or are too far into the future" num_dropped=429
level=warn ts=2019-07-07T05:46:02.960Z caller=scrape.go:952 component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=prometheus target=http://192.168.2.22:9100/metrics msg="appending scrape report failed" err="out of bounds"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after an incident on my Prometheus server which restarted for an OOM. The issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/8243) and [here](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/6554).

Theoretically, after passing the incorrectly set time data it should record metrics again.

If old data is not a concern you can drop your Prometheus data folder and restart the service as a quick solution.